# How to remove https:// from URL and insert http:// instead of it in string in PHP?

Tags: php, url

First, I need to check the URL string, if the protocol of URL is `https`,  then I need to replace `http` in PHP.
So the inputs and outputs of this php function must be like this:

```
Input -> https://example.com/example/https.php
Output-> http://example.com/example/https.php

Input -> http://example.com/example/https.php
Output-> http://example.com/example/https.php
```

Comment: nice example. quite rare here..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will ensure it's at the beginning of the string and it's followed by `://`

```
$input = 'https://example.com/example/https.php';
echo preg_replace('/^https(?=:\/\/)/i','http',$input);
```

Comment: I think regular expressions might be overkill for this situation.

Comment: Major +1 for this. Prevents problems with all the other answers thus far where there might be more than one `https` in a string.

Comment: @JustinSatyr I agree, this is right place for using `strncmp` or `strpos` (which is faster than `strncmp` in php when string begins with needle).

Comment: @ceejayoz Why do you prefer RegEx instead of Vyktor's answer ?

Comment: @JohnUS Because a regex allows you to use things like `^` to only affect the beginning of a string, which is a useful feature in this case. Any speed differences are going to be pretty negligible if you're not a huge site like Facebook.

Comment: Although I agree with @JustinSatyr I like using a single liner, that's why I suggested `preg_replace`.

Answer (score 4):

```
function remove_ssl ($url) {
    if (strpos($url, 'https://') == 0) {
        $url = 'http://' . substr($url, 7);
    }
    return $url;
}
```

The

```
strpos($url, 'https://') == 0
```

Is on purpose and is not === because we only want the case when the URL starts with https:// and just replace that one.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

```
...
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
if ($parsed_url['scheme'] == 'https') {
    $url = 'http://' . substr($url, 7);
}
return $url;
...
```

Comment: You may have `https://` multiple times in URL, it would be probably incorrect (some not URL-escaped entry) but it may happen: `https://..../index.php?source=https://...`.

Comment: Hh, on your update, what about URLs like `$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';`? :)) (but I like your way of thinking, +1)

Comment: Well, updated again...I believe that should work. Checks if it starts with https and only should only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: You've end up with my answer .)) so now I have nothing bad to say :) maybe that `strncmp` and/or `strpos` would be faster than `parse_url`, but this is a proper way to check protocol.

Answer (score 2):

At first you need to check `https` presence with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
if( strpos( $url, 'https://') === 0){
```

(notice `===`), than you may extract the all string after `https://` (that's after first 8 characters, or 5 when keeping original `://`) with [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$url = 'http://' . substr( $url, 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  $parse = parse_url($url);
  if($parse['scheme'] === 'https')
   {
  $url = str_replace('https','http',$url,1);
}
```

You can use this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `str_pos()` and `str_replace()` to accomplish this:

```
if(str_pos($input,'https:') === 0) {
    $output = str_replace('https:','http:',$input,1);
} else {
    $output = $input;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `=== 0` instead to be sure it is at the beginning of the string.

Comment: There can be "https:" in a string more than once.

Comment: @JustinSatyr good call. Updated answer to only replace the first instance of 'https:' and only if found at the beginning. (Notice the 4th `count` parameter added to str_replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
function replace_uri_protocol($uri, $search, $replacement){
    $parts = parse_url($uri);
    $uri = $replacement."://".$parts["host"].$parts["path"];

    if(isset($parts["query"])){
        $uri .= "?".$parts["query"];
    }       

    return $uri;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it's work on me..

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com';
 echo preg_replace("(^https?://)", "http://", $url);
```